# No backend available (GLMakie, CairoMakie, WGLMakie)

Tags: julia, agents.jl, makie.jl

I am following an Agents.jl tutorial (https://juliadynamics.github.io/Agents.jl/stable/examples/schelling/) and get the following error when executing this piece of code. Any ideas why?

```
using Agents
using InteractiveDynamics
using CairoMakie

groupColor(a) = a.group == 1 ? :blue : :green
groupMarker(a) = a.group == 1 ? :circle : :rect

fig, _ = abm_plot(model, ac = groupColor, am = groupMarker, as = 10)

#Note that abm_plot is a function from InteractiveDynamics.jl which uses makie
#and model is an AgentBasedModel obj created from Agents.jl

#Out > 
No backend available (GLMakie, CairoMakie, WGLMakie)!
Maybe you imported GLMakie but it didn't build correctly.
In that case, try `]build GLMakie` and watch out for any warnings.
If that's not the case, make sure to explicitely import any of the mentioned backends.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to update `InteractiveDynamics` package from 0.14.6 to 0.15.1. The answer to this problem can be found in the following thread.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/no-backend-available-glmakie-cairomakie-wglmakie/62984/6